# javascript jQuery stops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, action, document-ready

I have some `Jquery (mobile)` actions on the `.ready()` function in order to initialize the html elements with the correct values (passed as $def var):

If I comment this actions (see the end of the script) the script works perfectly (but obviously without the necessary html 'select' initial values).

If I use the actions the script runs ok (until the last action) but it never reaches the next statement '`get_status()`'...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var gauge_humidity1,
        gauge_temp1,
        gauge_temp2,
        gauge_temp3;


    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


        //### EVERYTHING WORK IF I COMMENT ALL THIS JQUERY'S ###
        //initiate sliders
        //OLD jQuery('#select_mode').val('$mode').slider('refresh');
        jQuery('#select_mode').val('$mode')
        jQuery('#select_r1_water').val('$r[0]');
        jQuery('#select_r2_heat').val('$r[1]');
        jQuery('#select_r345_window').val('$r[2]');
        jQuery('#select_r6_shadow').val('$r[5]');

        //initiate select_light
        jQuery('#select_light').val('$s_ini[2][5]');
        ### END OF COMMENT ###


        ### IF I UNCOMMENT THE GET_STATUS() NEVER RUNS ###
        get_status();
    });

</script>
```

```
        <form id="form_settings" action="" method="POST">
            <div id="section" data-role="collapsible-set">

                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                    <h3>
                        Control
                    </h3>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select_mode">
                            Modo
                        </label>
                        <select name="select_mode" id="select_mode" data-role="slider" onchange="update_mode()">
                            <option value="Manual">
                                Manual
                            </option>
                            <option value="Auto">
                                Auto
                            </option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Consider posting an example on www.jsfiddle.net - makes it easy for us to play around to see what works, what the errors are (if any), etc :)

Comment: first remove extra comma in `success: function(data) {},`

Comment: Don't use `.ready()` in JQM, use `pageinit` event if you want it to fire once `document` is initialized and inserted into DOM.

Comment: Thanks to all!
Joe (the tip was very useful)
Omar (It did the trick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `$(document).ready()`, the equivalent of `$(document).ready()` in **JQM** is `$(document).bind('pageinit')`

Just have a look at the jQuery Mobile documentation : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

> **Important:** `Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()`
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

**EDIT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#page_settings').bind('pageinit', function() {
         // Your code here
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution:

just added the 'pageinit' close to the html div data-role="page" and applied to '#page_settings' page (instead of document) since is were the controls are.

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page_settings">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#page_settings').bind('pageinit', function() {
            //initiate sliders
            jQuery('#select_mode').val('$mode').slider('refresh');
            jQuery('#select_r1_water').val('$r[0]').slider('refresh');
            jQuery('#select_r2_heat').val('$r[1]').slider('refresh');
            jQuery('#select_r345_window').val('$r[2]').slider('refresh');
            jQuery('#select_r6_shadow').val('$r[5]').slider('refresh');

            //initiate select_light
            jQuery('#select_light').val('$s_ini[2][5]').selectmenu('refresh');
        });
    </script>
```